# Concurrent programming in Java with return values

Tags: java, concurrency, return-value, future, nonblocking

I have a problem with concurrent programming in Java. I am working on my bachelor thesis and I have to make several methods which will return me a String value. In the Futures TriggerMessageFututre and getMeterValuesFuture is a process running which takes between 1-5 seconds and returns a String Value when it's finished.

The problem is now that future.get() is blocking my main thread. I want to call the TriggerMessage and the getMeterValue methode in my main without blocking my main thread and get their answer as a return value when they are finished. I wasn't able to find a way to solve my problem, because either it was a solution without return value or it was a solution which blocked the thread.

```
private String TriggerMessage(String Messagetyp) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException{
    Future<String> future = new communicator().TriggerMessageFuture(queue,centralSystem,Messagetyp);

    while(!future.isDone()) {
        System.out.println("[TriggerMessage]: Calculating... ");
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }

    String result = future.get(); //blocking
    return result;
}

private String getMeterValue(String key) throws Exception{
    Future<String> future = new communicator().getMeterValueFuture(queue,centralSystem,key);

    while(!future.isDone()) {
        System.out.println("[getMeterValue]: Calculating...");
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }

    String result = future.get(); //blocking
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Depends on what main thread is in your case? The thread `main(String[] args)` starts on, the Swing Event Dispatch Thread, Android's main thread?

Comment: `Future.get` is a blocking method. We cannot call blocking method without blocking. We can use `CountDownLatch` to help us to simplify operations.

Comment: `CountDownLatch` is still blocking.

Comment: it is also not clear how yo want to get a value that is not yet available (calculated) without waiting for it || or the main thread waits (blocks); or further processing of the result is *started* after the calculation

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what main thread are you referring to, plus if you can use `CompletableFuture`s instead of plain old Java `Future`s.

1. Using the `main(String[] args)` thread

It's not possible to do it without any form of blocking. If you are not blocking on `get`, you'll have to block on a `BlockingQueue` implementation, otherwise the main thread just ends.

2. Using the Swing Event Dispatch thread

You'd need to submit a continuation task which is not possible with `Future.get` from the outside. So either you include this submission inside the task `Future` has been created for, or switch to `CompletableFuture`

```java
ExecutorService exec = ...

Future<?> future = exec.submit(() -> {
   var value = someCalculation();
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
       useValueOnEDT(value);
   });
});
```

or

```java
CompletableFuture<ValueType> cf = ...

cf.whenComplete((value, error) -> {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        if (error != null) {
            handleErrorOnEdt(error);
        } else {
            useValueOnEDT(value);
        }
    });
});
```

3. Android Main Thread

The idea is the same as with Swing, but you'll have to use a Handler

```java
// given value
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> {
    useValueOnMainLooper(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `Future` into a `CompletableFuture` like so

```
static <T> CompletableFuture<T> from(Future<T> future) {
    var delegate = new CompletableFuture<T>();

    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        try {
            delegate.complete(future.get());
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            delegate.completeExceptionally(e);
        }
    });

    return delegate;
}
```

And then use that `CompletableFuture` to asynchronously handle the completion via its various `then...` and `when...` methods.